# Generating sets of the free group $F_k$ on $k$ generators

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Is it true that the free group $F_k$ on $k<\infty$ generators requires at least $k$ elements to generate. I.e. does every set which generates $F_k$ have cardinality at least $k$?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Sketch: any fewer than $k$ elements can't even generate the abelianization $\mathbb{Z}^k$.

Comment: Thanks :) I guess I can show that $\mathbb{Z}^k$ requires at least $k$ generators by embedding into $\mathbb{Q}^k$ and using linear algebra. Is there a more elementary way?

Comment: @Matt: you can look at the quotient $\mathbb{F}_2^k$ and use linear algebra over $\mathbb{F}_2$.